# Asp.net email validation on button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page that allows the user to send an email I just want to display a message alert to the user if the email was successfully send or not on the button click event is there a way that i can check if the email has been send successfully? and after the email has been send can i simple use 'textbox.text = "" 'to clear the controls on the page?

Below is the code for the button click event

```
protected void btnsendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            char[] split = { ';' };             
            foreach (string mailAdd in txtemailAdd.Text.Split(split))
            {
              sendMail(mailAdd);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
 }
```

Comment: http://www.ultradevelopers.net/Blog/16

Comment: You should also use the [post/redirect/get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern to avoid the user refreshing the page and resending the email. I.e. show your conf message on a **new** page that you redirect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) you can try this:-

```
message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
```

Answer (score 0):

make your function that sends email "sendMail(mailAdd);" return true or false depending on if email sent or not and display the message

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :-

```
protected void btnsendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            char[] split = { ';' };

            foreach (string mailAdd in txtemailAdd.Text.Split(split))
            {
              sendMail(mailAdd);


            }
          // mail is successfully sent :-
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Msg", "alert('Mail sent successfully')", true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                     // mail is not successfully sent :-
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Msg", "alert('Mail not sent successfully')", true);
        }
}
```